# Visual Studio 2017 SSIS Error (0xc001f041)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017

No matter which SQL Server version I use I get the following error when I try to drag common tasks (like Send Mail) into the Package:

> Failed to create the task.
>
> Cannot create a task from XML for task "", type "" due to error
>   0xC001F041 "Cannot create a task from XML. This occurs when the
>   runtime is unable to resolve the name to create a task. Verify that
>   the name is correct.".  (Sequence Container)"

I have no clue as to why that is happening and couldn't find any information on the internet either.

The strange thing is that I can drag the same tasks into the package when I use solutions that we've developed based on Sql Server 2008 R2 years ago. Restarting the machine didn't help. I could try to repair the Visual Studio installation, but I don't really want to lose all of my settings, extensions and such.

Apparently it works fine for a colleague. I deleted all .tbd-files in AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio, but neither of those files gets recreated when I start Visual Studio. I also tried to restore Toolbox defaults.

Executing the following command didn't help either. The same error is still appearing whenever I try to drop about 3/4 of the tasks into the package.

```
devenv /ResetSettings
devenv /setup
devenv /resetskippkgs
devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates
```

Comment: Which version of visual studio you are using ? Try to re-install the SSDT for the respective version of visual studio and give a try.

Comment: My guess is your package got corrupted.   Does it only happen on one package, or does it also happen if you create a new package from scratch?

Comment: @user1076774 I use VS 2017 professional with the most current version. I started the repair-tool before leaving for the weekend and that actually seemed to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only thing that actually helps is to repair VS.